# Matching a variable with members of a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, variables, match

I want to check if a value of a variable matches (==) with a value of any member of a given list, on a single line

Answer (score 6):

use `in`:

```
> lst = [1,'r']
> v = 1
> v in lst
True
```

Comment: *cough* shadowing `list` is bad *cough*

Comment: true, it was just for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: I'll leave this answer cos generator expressions are useful beasts (especially together with `any` and `all`) but if you are just testing for membership in the list then you should use `in`.

---

```
any(var == i for i in my_list)
```

Explanation:

[`any`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any) is a function which takes an iterable object and returns True if any element of that iterable is True.

The list comprehension `[x == i for i in my_list]` is a list of boolean values comparing `x` to each value in the list in turn. If any of them is True then `x == i`. So if you call `any` on that list you will get the answer you want.

If you change the `[]` to `()` in writing a list comprehension you get a generator object instead, which makes the values one at a time instead of constructing them in memory. And if you are passing a generator expression as the only argument to a function, you can omit the extra set of parentheses, to leave the neat syntax above.

There is also a function `all`.

Comment: It's much better to use `var in my_list`